# Take photo with windows phone 8.1 javascript app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I am making a Javascript Universal Windows 8.1 app and I can't get the camera to work in the phone version. Here is the code I am using that fires when a button is touched:

```
var captureUI = new Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();
  captureUI.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo).then(function (capturedItem) {
     if (capturedItem) {
         console.log(capturedItem);
     }
     else {
         console.log("error");
     }
  });
```

It's throwing an error on the first line "Object doesn't support this action". What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Have you selected de `Webcam` capability in your manifest? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx

Comment: I turned on enterprise, internet, location, pictures library and webcam. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureui.aspx), `Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI` is not supported in Windows Phone 8.1

For Windows Phone (8.1) you need to use the `Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx

Comment: Ok Thank you. I cannot find a javascript only example of using this class. Do you have one?